# How to integrate a graph from a plotly into a specific area on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, plotly-python

I have a website that I implemented using flask. I also have a Python module that creates a graph. I would like to place it in my template in a specific container. `Important`: there is only one page, and I would not like to update it or make redirects.

In the documentation I found this example:

```py
import plotly.express as px
from jinja2 import Template

data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')

output_html_path=r"/path/to/output.html"
input_template_path = r"/path/to/template.html"

plotly_jinja_data = {"fig":fig.to_html(full_html=False)}
#consider also defining the include_plotlyjs parameter to point to an external Plotly.js as described above

with open(output_html_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
    with open(input_template_path) as template_file:
        j2_template = Template(template_file.read())
        output_file.write(j2_template.render(plotly_jinja_data))
```

And:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Here's a Plotly graph!</h1>
  {{ fig }}
  <p>And here's some text after the graph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But as I understand it, this is not entirely suitable for me. Since the template engine injects data before the page renders.

A little later, I tried to insert a graph by calling the `flask` controller, which gave me all the graph code, and tried to insert it into the container. All the necessary content was indeed inserted into the page, but the graph was not displayed:

```py
@app.route('/get_plot')
def get_plot():
    data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
    fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
    plotly_jinja_data = {"fig": fig.to_html(full_html=False)}

    return jsonify(plotly_jinja_data)
```

HTML (Out of desperation, I even connected the cdn `plotly` script, idk for what...):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.27.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="block" style="height: 50px;"><button id="btn" onclick="get_plot()">GET</button></div>
    <div class="block" id="external">
    </div>

</div>

<script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also JavaScript (unfortunately, I’m not very good at it yet):

```js
async function get_plot() {
    const response = await fetch('/get_plot');
    const div = document.getElementById('external');
    let res_json = await response.json();
    div.innerHTML = res_json.fig;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the graph via AJAX and display it within a container, you can use Plotly's own JSON encoder to convert the data to JSON or simply use the [`to_json()`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.io.to_json.html) function and send it to the frontend. There the received data is used to display the graph in the elements specified by the id via `Plotly.react(...)`.

```py
import plotly.express as px
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get-plot')
def get_plot():
    data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
    fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
    return fig.to_json()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <button id="btn">GET</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block" id="external"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.27.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
(function() {
    const btnElem = document.getElementById('btn');
    btnElem && btnElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        fetch('/get-plot')
            .then(resp => resp.ok && resp.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (!data) return;
                Plotly.react('external', data, {}); 
            });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! PS: The question is a little off topic, do you know why people click on the button to lower the reputation in question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see any reason to downvote the question and didn't.